# Joining 2 tables where multiple matches occur, and create text column for multiple values

Tags: mysql, sql, database, join

How can I create a view which has a `text` columnType called `fileTags`, whose value is a grouping of all instances of the `fileTag`.`tag` column whose `imgId` matches the `file`.`imgId`? (Also, this view would end up having a lot more joins than just this one.)

My `file` table

```
+-------+----------+
| imgId | filename |
+-------+----------+
| 10    | dog.jpg  |
+-------+----------+
| 20    | cat.jpg  |
+-------+----------+
| 30    | bird.jpg |
+-------+----------+
```

My `fileTag` table

```
+----+--------+----------+
| id | tag    | imgId    |
+----+--------+----------+
| 1  | fur    | 10       |
+----+--------+----------+
| 2  | paw    | 10       |
+----+--------+----------+
| 3  | leash  | 10       |
+----+--------+----------+
| 4  | feline | 20       |
+----+--------+----------+
```

My intended goal. A `getFiles` view (Join by imgId and create a text column that contains all labels)

```
+-------+----------+-----------------------+
| imgId | filename | fileTags              |
+-------+----------+-----------------------+
| 10    | dog.jpg  | ["fur","paw","leash"] |
+-------+----------+-----------------------+
| 20    | cat.jpg  | ["feline","litter"]   |
+-------+----------+-----------------------+
| 30    | bird.jpg | ["beak","wings"]      |
+-------+----------+-----------------------+
```

My View Design Attempt

```
SELECT
    `file`.`imgId` AS `imgId`,
     GROUP_CONCAT(`fileTag`.`tag`) AS `tags`
FROM
(
  `file`
    JOIN `fileTag` ON(
        (
            `file`.`imgId` = `fileTag`.`imgId`
        )
    )
)
GROUP BY `fileTag`.`imgId`
```

**My Problem**

- If I do a JOIN, the performance is great but it is only returning rows in which that imgId has a fileTag. I need all file's returned even if they do not have a fileTag.
- If I do a LEFT JOIN, the performance is really bad. If I run an EXPLAIN I can see that it indexes way too many rows for each table.
  [image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT f.imgId, GROUP_CONCAT(ft.tag) AS tags
FROM file f LEFT JOIN
     filetag ft
     ON f.imgId = ft.imgId
GROUP BY f.imgId;
```

One comment:  All the parentheses and backticks makes the query more difficult to write and to understand.

Performance should be fine with an index on `filetab(imgId, tag)`.

With the same index, you might find that a correlated subquery is faster:

```
SELECT f.imgId,
       (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ft.tag) 
        FROM filetag ft
        WHERE f.imgId = ft.imgId
       ) AS tags
FROM file f ;
```

This avoids the outer `GROUP BY`, which can be a performance win.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this out with the index.

Comment: That performance is way better! But whenever I run an explain, instead of 4180 and 9984 rows, I get 4180 and 5. Is there any way I could get it down to 4180 and 1? Sorry if I'm not speaking proper language. I was always taught that when doing an explain, only 1 of the items should have more than 1 row.

Comment: @jmchauv . . . Sorry.  I have no idea about what you were taught.

Comment: Sorry. I should have phrased that better. I guess I don't have a complete understanding of the 'rows' column whenever I run an EXPLAIN on the view within navicat.